# Why does $ U \cap (X − \{x_1, . . . , x_m\})$ not intersect the set $A-\{x\}$ at all?

Tags: general-topology

Munkre Topology section 17

Theorem 17.9.

Let X be a space satisfying the $T_1$ axiom; let $A$ be a subset of $X$.
Then the point $x$ is a limit point of $A$ if and only if every neighborhood of $x$ contains infinitely many points of A.
[image]

My question is why does $ U \cap (X − \{x_1, \dots , x_m\})$ not intersect the  set $A-\{x\}$ at all?

Comment: We know that $U\cap (A-\{x\})=\{x_1,...,x_m\}$ and we have removed those points from $X$. $U\cap (X-\{x_1,...,x_m\})\subset U$ so the result follows.

Comment: thanks u @JohnDouma

Comment: A more succint  proof: In a $T_1$ space every finite subset is closed . Suppose  there is an open set $U$ with $x\in U,$ such that $U\cap (A-\{x\})$ is finite. Then  $U\cap (A-\{x\})$ is closed. An open set minus a closed set is open so $U-(U\cap (A-\{x\}))$ is an open set containing $ x$ but disjoint from $A-\{x\}$.

Comment: thanksu @DanielWainfleet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(A-\{x\})\cap U=\{x_1,\dots,x_m\}$

so:

$(A-\{x\})\cap U\cap(X-\{x_1,\dots,x_m\})=\{x_1,\dots,x_m\}\cap(X-\{x_1,\dots,x_m\})=\varnothing$

Comment: thanks a lots@drhab

Comment: You are welcome.