# Question on a Theorem about $T_1$ axiom

Tags: general-topology

A similar question [was asked here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2754798/why-does-u-cap-x-%E2%88%92-x-1-x-m-not-intersect-the-set-a-x-at), but my question is slightly different. Munkres' Topology, presents the following theorem:

> Let $X$ be a space satisfying $T_1$ axiom; let $A$ be a subset of $X$. p: Then the point $x$ is a limit point of $A$ if and only if q: every neighborhood of $x$ contains infinitely many points of $A$.

Then to prove $p \Rightarrow q$, it is shown that $$U \cap (X-\{x_1, ...,x_m\})$$ is a neighborhood of $x$ that intersects the set $A-\{x\}$ not at all. I understand why the intersection is empty but I am not sure why the set $$U \cap (X-\{x_1, ...,x_m\})$$
must be a neighborhood of $x$ that intersects $x$ in at least another point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x$ is a limit point of $A$ if every neighborhood of $x$ contains a point of $A$ other than $x$. Recall that a neighborhood in the sense of Munkres
is always an open set.

$p \Rightarrow q$:

Assume that there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ which contains only finitely many points of $A$. Then also $F = (U \cap A) \setminus \{x\}$ is finite and we have $x \notin F$. In a $T_1$-space all finite subsets are closed, thus $F$ is closed in $X$. Hence $V = U \setminus F$ is a neigborhood of $x$ which by definition does not contain any point of $A$ other than $x$.

Comment: My question is why $V$ must be an open neighborhood? I understand we show it is not and we reach a contradiction. $V$ is an open set in $X$ and it intersects $x$, but why does it have to intersect $A$ in at least another element?

Comment: Since $F$ is closed, $X \setminus F$ is open, hence $V = U \setminus F = U \cap (X \setminus F)$ is open. We have $x \in U, x \notin F$. Thus $x \in V$. Let $y \in  V  \cap A$. This means $y \in U, y \notin F, y \in A$. Thus $y \in U \cap A$, but $y \notin F = (U \cap A) \setminus \{x\}$. Hence $y = x$. This shows that $V$ contains no point of $A$ other than $x$ itself which contradicts $p$.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. So just to clarify, does it contradict because $V$ is open in $X$ and it intersects $x$ and $x$ is a limit point of $A$ so $V$ must also intersect $A$ in at least one more element other than $x$ but it does not, which is a contradiction? If that is the case then my main source of confusion is the part that $V$ is open $X$ (which I understand). I thought to use openness we have to show $V$ is open in $A$ not in $X$, which is not necessarily true as far as I know.

Comment: The contradiction is that under the assumption that $U \cap A$ is finite for some neigborhood $U$, then there exists a smaller neigborhood $V$ which contains **no** points of $A$ except possibly $x$ itself (if $x \notin A$, which can of course occur, then $V$ does not contain any point of $A$).

Answer (score 0):

It does not, which is the contradiction.

The hypothesis that there is a "neighborhood $U$ of $x$ intersects $A$ in only $\textit{finitely}$ many points"  has allowed us to create this set as a neighborhood of $x$ that does not intersect $A - \{x \} $ which means $x$ is $\textit{not}$ a limit point of $A$.

So we have:  (not q) $\Rightarrow$ (not p)